# How to consume API Rest (Google Cloud SQL) using a Google Service Account

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, retrofit, service-accounts

I have one Google Cloud SQL database and I have one API that return some JSON infos. I would like consume this API in Android using a google account service, I already created one account service in google cloud platform, but I cannot find any example in google about how to use retrofit with google account service.

Can you please help me understand it? or could you give me examples?

thanks.

Comment: I understand you have built an API in App Engine that serves JSON response from the data it extracted from your CloudSQL instance, am I right? And you'd like to authenticate your Android client's requests to your App Engine API with the credentials from your logged in users in Android with Google accounts?

Comment: Yes, I have an API Engine that serves JSON response, but I would like that Android client's request to my APP Engine API using an unique credentials (a google server account).
I find a documentation that explain about google service account:
take a look: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
but I cannot find any example about how to implement it.

Comment: Service accounts aren't meant to authenticate mobile apps to APIs. They provide a way to authenticate a server (like your App Engine app) to other servers (like the CloudSQL API or other Google APIs). Is your application managing user-specific data?

Comment: No, my application does not managing user-specific data. it's possible I connect with my google cloud sql in android using API key or using a google cloud server account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LundinCast said, service accounts are used for server to server authentication [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#what_are_service_accounts), not individual users.

For connecting from Android to Cloud SQL, the only way I can imagine is by using Cloud Endpoints [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) as an intermediary. So the connection schema would be like this:

Android Client <-> Cloud Endpoint <-> Cloud SQL

Here it's the documentation for calling a backend API from an Android Client [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/calling-from-android).